# Anaconda and OpenMDAO

Tags: python, anaconda, openmdao

I'm new in Python and am trying to use [WISDEM](https://nwtc.nrel.gov/WISDEM) that is designed as a OpenMDAO plugin-in. I'd like to use Anaconda (with OS X). Which Anaconda's version(2.7/3.5) will work with OpenMDAO?

Thanks,

-Luis

Answer (score 0):

Which version of OpenMDAO/WISDEM are you using? If its tied to OpenMDAO <= V0.0.13 then you can't use anaconda.

OpenMDAO >= V1 will work with anaconda though. There was a major change in OpenMDAO between 0.0.13 and 1.0 and support for anaconda was introduced there.